# Can't run application in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

How to install application in android device using android studio.i had may try but i can't find solution as i want so please help me,please see below screen shots

```
Waiting for device.
Target device: xiaomi-mi_3w-13d8da8
Uploading file
local path: E:\Mahesh\Android\StudioWorkspace\Test\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.test
Installing com.test
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.test"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.test
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT]
```

Thank you in advance[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't upload Android app to device (stale dexed jars)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25493310/cant-upload-android-app-to-device-stale-dexed-jars)

Comment: @sufiyan i try this but i don't know what i do exacly in studio,beacuse i am new in studio.Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error clearly states that you need to remove installed application from your device and install it again. If it doesn't work, try to enable proguard for your release/debug builds:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

You need to add this code into the `build.gradle` file, inside the section called `android`. More info on Gradle in Android Studio can be found [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Types).

Comment: Thank you..I don't have proguard-android.txt in tools,after i add this file my code is working perfact.thank you

Comment: For me also it doesnot worked:( @ElhananMishraky is it working at your end? If so then what solution you get?