# Android Studio error "installation failed since the device possibly has stale dexed jars"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I formated my computer
and installed Android Studio

Before that my app was working fine,
after formating and installing Android Studio
I keep getting this error
"installation failed since the device possibly has stale dexed jars"

and in every emulator I open I get "Storage Space running out!" although I just installed Android Studio and my first time to run my app,  not sure how got full?
and not sure if this is the reason for dexed jars issue too

Any advise?

Thanks

Comment: Check out this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25493310/cant-upload-android-app-to-device-stale-dexed-jars

Comment: This worked for me http://stackoverflow.com/a/31733397/2091181

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me:

In Android Studio this can be done by clicking on **Build > Clean Project**.

Comment: This is the first answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25493310/cant-upload-android-app-to-device-stale-dexed-jars

Comment: I tried that, did not work. It might be related to the storage space, i tried to change the size in the config.ini to 1024MB but still same both problems

Comment: weird thing, it got fixed after restarting the computer

Answer (score 2):

Disable the instant run.
This is a known issue of instant run.

Comment: As the Android platform has continued to grow, so has the size of Android apps. When your application and the libraries it references reach a certain size, you encounter build errors that indicate your app has reached a limit of the Android app build architecture.