# Issue while installing app from android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, installation

I got this issue when i install my app in the android device with api level above 20

/packageName E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

When install the same app in android devices with api level 20 getting this issue

```
Installation failed since the device possibly has stale dexed jars that don't match the current version (dexopt error). In order to proceed, you have to uninstall the existing application.
```

WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!

Do you want to uninstall the existing application?

Can anyone help me with this issue.

Comment: post your manifest file code

Comment: just uninstall previous app ,that will fix it

Answer (score 1):

If someone comes here looking for answers, here's what I did..

Close Emulator.

Tools > AVD Manager > Select Emulator Settings > Wipe Data > Cold Boot..

Now Install App.

Answer (score 0):

Clean and Rebuild your application and also restart your device. It will surely help you.