# Cannot run instrumented tests of a library on older devices

Tags: android, android-instrumentation

On older devices (I tested v10 and 15), I cannot install any debug app build without using ProGuard because of this problem: [Can't upload Android app to device (stale dexed jars)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25493310/cant-upload-android-app-to-device-stale-dexed-jars)

Using ProGuard temporarily for the debug build with options -dontobfuscate and implicit shrinking reduces the number of methods and so allows running the app on those devices. Currently, I have found no other solution.

The same problem comes up when trying to run instrumented tests of my library on old devices. To allow code shrinking separately for this library, I changed its build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
...
android {
    ..
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources false
            testProguardFile 'proguard-rules.pro'
            // or testProguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

(Hint: The library debug build is usually irrelevant for all builds besides instrumented tests because Android always uses release builds if the library is built as a dependency.)

Executing an instrumented Test of my library on an emulator (v15), I get the following kinds of errors:

```
Error:(19, 33) error: package my.proj....Config does not exist
Error:(18, 31) error: cannot find symbol variable ClassName
```

**It does not find any symbols of the default source set of the library itself. This only happens with `minifyEnabled true`.** How can this happen?